# Link index.html client.js and server.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server, client

I'm starting with Node.js and I have already a problem in my first program. Below is the code I'm using. Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Random Temperatures</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="tb" name="tb" />
    <input type="button" value="Random Number!" id="myButton" name="myButton"/>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Client.js:

```
const textBox = document.getElementById('tb');
const button = document.getElementById('myButton');
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    textBox.value = rnd;
});
```

Server.js:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(response);
var fs = require('fs');
app.listen(8080);
console.log("App running…");
function response(req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html',
    function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end('Failed to load file index.html');
        }
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}
```

When I start the application I go to the browser the text box and the button appear. But in the browser console I'm getting these errors:

> client.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>
> ContentScript.js:112 Exception in onResRdy: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'htmlRes' of undefined
>
> localhost/:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish
>   connection. Receiving end does not exist.

I guess my problem is the linking between the 3 files but I tried several things and I can't solve the problem. I'm sure it's a stupid error but forgive me I'm just getting start. Any advice?

Comment: I have seen this error come from McAfee chrome extension. Does it throws the same error in incognito mode or some other browser?

Comment: I'm getting these errors in Firefox: localhost:8080 >> The script from “http://localhost:8080/client.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type. ||||| client.js:1 >> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' ||||| Stylesheets without CSSOM changes reparsed to check for errors. Refresh the page to also see errors from stylesheets changed from CSSOM and from style attributes.

Comment: But you don't see any error in my code regarding file links?

Comment: nah, looks good to me

Comment: For sure something tiny is wrong... ;-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser (because you have `<script src="/client.js">`) makes a request for `/client.js`

The server:

1. Gets the request
2. Runs `response`
3. Reads `index.html`
4. Sends it to the browser

Since `index.html` starts with `<`, the browser throws an error when it tries to run it as JavaScript.

**Why are you giving the browser `index.html` when it asks for `client.js`?**

You need to examine the request object, determine what URL is being asked for, write logic to return the *correct* resource with the correct status code and the correct content-type, and then return that to the client.

The [Node.js documentation has an example of this](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/) but you should probably stop trying to use `createServer` directly — since it involves a massive amount of wheel reinvention — switch to using [Express](https://expressjs.com/) and work through the (very short) [getting started guide](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html) which includes a section on using the `static` module to serve up static files.