# Reading a json file in JavaScript returns only the HTML code

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm trying to open a json file in JavaScript in order to modify and display it. There is plenty of ways to do it around here on Stack Overflow. However, when using the following method, my data only contains a string of my html code, which I find very strange!

```
    function loadFile(filePath) {
      var result = null;
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET", filePath, false);
      xmlhttp.send();
      console.log('test1')
      if (xmlhttp.status==200) {
          console.log('test2')
        result = xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
      console.log('test3')
      return result;
    }

var mystuff=loadFile("./mydata.json");
alert(mystuff); // Here in mystuff I have only the content of my html code
```

and I call it with :

```
<script  src="/script.js"></script>
```

Even if I achieve (that's not the case yet) to open my .json, I'd like to know why my code returned my html code, and not the content of my file.

Comment: Did you confirm your JSON file does in fact just contain JSON and didn't somehow get saved as HTML?

Comment: If it's returning HTML then the URL `./mydata.json` resolves to some HTML.

Comment: `xmlhttp.open("GET", filePath, false);` — synchronous XHR is deprecated for good reason. Don't do that.

Comment: What about using fetch for json files? fetch( filePath ).then( res=>{res.json().then(json=>{console.log(json})})

Comment: I confirm it is indeed a JSON file, and even if it was,the file returned is my exact HTML page where the .js is launched. It might be indeed an issue about synchronous XHR, I'll check if I got the same issue with another method. 

Thank you all !

Comment: @EthanHermsey — Doesn't solve the problem of the URL not returning JSON. It'll just throw an exception trying to parse the HTML as JSON (or possibly because it gets a 404 Not Found response with an HTML body)

Comment: @Guenaoueg — While you might have a file with that name containing JSON, if the URL is returning HTML then it is returning HTML. Currently betting you have a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572302/link-index-html-client-js-and-server-js

Comment: It'd help if you showed us a screenshot or the raw content of the HTML you're returning, particularly with browser headers from your browser's "Inspect/Network" tool if possible.  What do you see? https://www.codexworld.com/how-to/monitor-ajax-requests-google-chrome/

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, you're right.. If should throw an error...

Comment: I figured out what was wrong : I was running my code with Node.js in order to have an easy development environment (npm start). So the loadFile(./mydata.json) was calling http://localhost:1234/mydata.json . I managed to get rid of this by opening my file through another server, opened thanks to `http-server -c-1 --cors`(http-server is another node package, and the --cors is necessary because otherwise Chrome refuse to open the file). Thank you all for your help !