# Doctype html err

Tags: html, node.js, syntax-error

i have a error, here the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="get" function="getInfo">Get Information</button>
    <script src="../server/app.js"></script>
    <script>
    function getInfo() {
        request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('Status: ' + response && response.statusCode)
        console.log('Body: ' + body)
    })
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the error is very strange, look:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

thanx in advance for all suggestions!
P.S sorry for bad english!

Comment: Where is this code `<!DOCTYPE html>` in your file? What's the file extension you saved?

Comment: sorry, stack overflow not include the first line, my file has .html extension

Comment: Something is trying to parse the HTML as not-HTML (quite likely JS or JSON) but there isn't enough context to tell what.

Comment: When and Where that error show up ?

Comment: Given this is tagged [tag:node.js], even money says it will turn out to be yet another duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572302/link-index-html-client-js-and-server-js

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui the error show up when i run the code

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but I think you are running html file with nodeJS.

Make sure your command is `node .\file.js` instead of `node .\file.html`