# How to access an .html file from a .mjs file on a VPS

Tags: html, node.js, websocket, socket.io, vps

I am trying to set up a basic websocket using socket.io on example.com, which runs on a VPS. For the content, I have a index.mjs file and an index.html. I call the html within the mjs:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

At /var/www/html I can place an html file which will be used when you open example.com.
There is also the root folder, in which I parked the node-modules, index.mjs, package.json and index.html as well.
I had thought I would launch index.mjs from root, which then reads into the index.html at the same file location, but the website remains blank. I am sure that I am missing something here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
// can now use `require` in an ESM

const app = require("express")();
const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
const options = { /* ... */ };

const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://example.com",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
    credentials: true
  }
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

httpServer.listen(8000);
```

Comment: Hello, could you show us the full example code of `index.mjs` please

Comment: Yes sure! I added the code

Comment: Does the HTML document contain only content? Or does it only contain script elements that request resources for which Express returns a 404 error? I expect [this is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572302/link-index-html-client-js-and-server-js) but there isn't sufficient debugging information in the question to tell for sure.