# MIME type conflict with external JS File dynamically creating html elements

Tags: javascript, html, mime-types

I try to create html Elements dynamically with an external JS File.
But Firefox tells me that there is some MIME-Type Conflict.
I use the type=("text/javascript") since it is a JS File.
I tried all sorts of different types from "text/html" to "application/javascript"
but nothing worked.

Thanks in advance!

My html file:

````
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vortrags Wizard</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="./sectionCreator.js" ></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class=container>
        <div class="header"> <h1>Vortrags Wizard!</h1></div>
        
            <div id= "areaID" class="questionArea"></div>

            <div class="commitArea"></div>

            <div class="footer"></div>
            </div>

   </div>
</body>


</html> 

My JS file:

function createSection(className,content){
    
    var section = document.createElement("section");

    section.classList.add(className);

    section.innerHTML = content;
    
    return section;
}

window.onload = function(){
    var area = document.getElementById("areaID");
    area.appendChild(createSection("testClass","testContent"));
}```

Error Message:(German)
>Die Ressource von "http://127.0.0.1:5501/sectionCreator.js" wurde wegen eines MIME-Typ-Konfliktes ("text/html") blockiert (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

My Translation:
The Ressource was blocked due to an MIME-Type-Conflict ("text/html")
````

Comment: The **server** says that the URL points to an HTML document. The `type` attribute just tells the browser what to expect and has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: This is probably another duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572302/link-index-html-client-js-and-server-js) but you didn't include a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a server, check in case the first 'dot' on './sectionCreator.js' could be sending the request to the wrong route or directory and also make sure the response has the header 'Content-Type: text/javascript' only if the js file is being loaded dynamically through the application code.

Comment: It's really rare for a URL ending in `.js` to be JS with an HTML content-type. Usually the problem is that it really it as HTML document, so just telling the browser it is JS won't help.

Comment: When MIME sniffing is disabled, the browser stops trying to guess the MIME type, instead it relies on the 'Content-Type' response header. It is like that due to the [MIME sniffing vulnerability](https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-mime-sniffing) that attackers can exploit to perform [Cross Site Scripting attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/)

Comment: What does that have to do with the question? The error message says that `Content-Type` is `text/html` which is probably because the resource is HTML. Your recommendation to turn off `nosniff` and make the site vulnerable to the MIME sniffing exploit you linked to won't turn that HTML document into JS.

Comment: If the resource is HTML, the error would say something like this: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: It would only do that if it tried to execute the HTML as JS. It *doesn't* try to execute the HTML as JS because the Content-Type is `text/html` so it says *Resource blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)*  instead.