# How do I link a js file to index.html in a Node.js web server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to Node.js and I'm just trying to create simple web server that can serve HTML, JS, and CSS files.

The server works and I can view `index.html` in localhost. But I can't seem to link the `request.js` to `index.html`. Here's my project structure:

```
--public
----js
------request.js
----index.html
--app.js
```

app.js

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const host = 'localhost';
const port = 8000;

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html")
        .then(contents => {
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
            res.writeHead(200); // success status code
            res.end(contents);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.writeHead(500);
            res.end(err);
            return;
        });
};

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(port, host, function(error)  {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Something went wrong', error)
    }
    else {
        console.log(`Server is running on http://${host}:${port}`);
    }
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <script src="/js/request.js" defer></script>
    <title>Water Web Dev</title>
<body>

</body>
</html>
</head>
```

request.js

```
const axios = require('axios');
const getBtn = document.getElementById('get-btn');

const getData = () => {
    axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/unknown')
        .then(function (response) {
            // success
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // error
            console.log(error);
        })
        .then(function () {
            // always executed
        });
}

getBtn.addEventListener('click', getData)
```

[image: project structure]

Comment: You need to make your scripts public, See https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Please read [ask]. Don't post pictures of text. Do provide a [mcve]. The server says the URL you are asking for is an HTML document. You need to provide a URL that points to your JS. Either you haven't given the JS a URL (we can't tell you haven't shown us the code that runs the server) or you just made a typo and didn't provide the right URL. Possibly a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572302/link-index-html-client-js-and-server-js

Comment: My apologies. I have provided the way I linked the files. In `index.html`, I used a relative path to `request.js`. It might be the source of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should server your css & js files as static files.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Move it to a static folder?