# EJS: How to properly link stylesheets and javascript files in ejs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

I have ran into an issue when using ejs to link external stylesheets and script tags. Here is my link for my stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css">
```

When I highlight the link to the sheet and follow it (in VScode) I am brought to the correct file. I know it is going to the correct location for sure.

However, when I run this on my localhost:5000 I get an error. Here is what the error reads.

Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:5000/styles/index.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I notice this is pointing to my localhost:5000/styles/index.css, but I do not want it to point to my local host, I want it to point to the directories I have set up in my file structure.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: EJS is completely irrelevant to this problem. `http://localhost:5000/styles/index.css` is not a URL to a stylesheet. You need a URL to a stylesheet. "I do not want it to point to my local host, I want it to point to the directories I have set up in my file structure" — You can't link to `file:///` scheme URLs from a page served over `http://`. You need to give the stylesheet an `http://` URL and use that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572302/link-index-html-client-js-and-server-js  is probably a duplicate but the question lacks a [mcve] of the server code.

Answer (score -1):

if u are trying to use ejs in a nodejs project with express ,u should first define a folder that contain all the static files like css and images then give permission to the browser to get this file .check this:
**https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: GOTCHA! I remember learning about that when I first started reading up on express. Thank you so much this solves my problem. I know enough to resolve things from here!

Comment: you are welcome,can you add the right badge to the  answer so others can see it.andi think the answer is clear for those who faced the same problem